# How can i generate the number of words with the same number of characters?

Tags: c, arrays, kernighan-and-ritchie

I am learning c programming language by k&r and i come across this exercise "Write a program to print a histogram of the lengths of words in its input. It is easy to draw the histogram with the bars horizontal; a vertical orientation is more challenging"and i decided to make a little bit changes to the question and so this is what I've gotten so far :

```
 #include <stdio.h>
    #define OUT 0
    #define IN 1
    main(){
        int c, nw, nc, i,state,j;
        nw = nc = 0;

        while ((c = getchar()) != EOF){
            if (c == '\n' || c == '\t' || c == ' ')
                state = OUT;
            else if (state == OUT) {
                state = IN;
                ++nw;
            }


    if (state == IN) {
                    if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z')
    ++nc;
    if ( c >='0' && c<='9')
    ++nc;
            }
        }
        printf("Lengths of words");
        for (j = 1; j < 10; ++j){
                printf("[%d]-%d", j, nw);
        }
     }
```

and so this is what i expect the computer to print out:

```
 Lengths of words
    [0]- nw with > 10 characters
    [1]- nw with 1 character
    [2]- nw with 2 characters
    [3]- nw with 3 characters
    ...
```

For example: `my name is linh` and this is what it will print:

```
[0]- 0
[1]- 0
[2]- 2
[3]- 0
[4]- 0
...
```

I know this exercise is about array and hence,I might have left out its concept in this program and would need someone to correct me on this :)I'm eager to know how can i generate the number of words with the same number of characters. Also, i would like my code to be reviewed as somehow...i believe there are some misconceptions in it. I am comparatively new to C and any kind helps from you would be greatly appreciated :) Thank you in advance!

Comment: i suppose the second one should be `in` but why?

Comment: How do you expect this code to count the words of different lengths when you print the same number, `nw`, every time in the last loop? Also, your two `(state == OUT)` conditions arethe same, and even if you change state in the first block, the second will never be checked because of the `else`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to solve your problem. I hope it will help you and it is enough simple to be clear for you.

```html
 #include <stdio.h>

typedef int bool;
#define true 1
#define false 0
#define maxNumOfWords 10

char *createHistogram(int n) {
    char *hist = (char *)malloc((n + 1) * sizeof(char));
    if (hist == NULL) {
        return "";
    }
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        hist[i] = '*';
    }
    hist[i] = '\0';
    return hist;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    bool isInWord = false;
    int results[maxNumOfWords];
    int index = -1;
    int j;
    char c;

    // initialize the result array to 0
    for (j = 0; j < maxNumOfWords; j++) {
        results[j] = 0;
    }
    while ((index < maxNumOfWords) && ((c = getchar()) != EOF)) {
        switch (c) {
        case '\n':
        case '\r':
        case '\t':
        case ' ':
            isInWord = false;
            break;
        default:
            // on the beginning of the first word
            if (isInWord == false) {
                ++index;
            }
            isInWord = true;
            if ((c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') || (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') || (c >= '0' && c <= '9'))
                results[index] += 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    printf("Lengths of words:\n");
    for (j = 0; j < maxNumOfWords; j++) {
        int n = results[j];
        printf("[%d]-%d %s\n", j, n, createHistogram(n));
    }
}
```

Comment: I do not quite understand as i am just a newbie to C. However, i truly appreciate your effort in helping me with this problem sincerely. I will surely take this as my preference when i have a stronger grasp of C. Once again, thank you for your help :)